# Install LXQt on Centos 7 (from EPEL)

Tags: centos, lxqt

I've been looking for how to install LXQt on Centos 7. I did notice some lxtq packages in EPEL, but there seems to be no main package for whole desktop. Can somebody point to me how (or if) can it can be installed from EPEL repository?

I have epel-release package installed.

```
# yum search lxqt
Zavedené moduly: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.karneval.cz
 * epel: mirror.karneval.cz
 * extras: mirror.karneval.cz
 * updates: mirror.karneval.cz
============================ N/S matched: lxqt =================================
liblxqt.x86_64 : Core shared library for LXQt desktop suite
liblxqt-devel.x86_64 : Devel files for liblxqt
liblxqt-mount.x86_64 : Mount utility library for LXQt Desktop Suite
liblxqt-mount-devel.x86_64 : Devel files for liblxqt-mount
lxqt-about.x86_64 : About application for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-common.noarch : Common resources for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-config.x86_64 : Config tools for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-globalkeys.x86_64 : Global keys utility for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-globalkeys-devel.x86_64 : Developer files for lxqt-globalkeys
lxqt-notificationd.x86_64 : Notification daemon for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-openssh-askpass.x86_64 : Askpass openssh transition dialog for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-panel.x86_64 : Main panel bar for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-panel-devel.x86_64 : Developer files for lxqt-panel
lxqt-policykit.x86_64 : PolicyKit agent for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-powermanagement.x86_64 : Powermanagement daemon for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-qtplugin.x86_64 : Qt plugin framework for LXQt Desktop Suite
lxqt-runner.x86_64 : Application runner agent for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-session.x86_64 : Main session for LXQt desktop suite
lxqt-wallet.x86_64 : Create a kwallet like functionality for LXQt
lxqt-wallet-devel.x86_64 : Development files for lxqt-wallet
lximage-qt.x86_64 : The image viewer and screenshot tool for LXQt
lxqt-sudo.x86_64 : GUI frontend for sudo/su
pcmanfm-qt.x86_64 : LxQt file manager PCManFM
```

Comment: You can install it when you didnt get any dependency errors. You can not install it when you missed some rpm packages from EPEL repos.You should find another repos to provide some missing rpm packages.

Comment: @supriady Sorry, I don`t get you. I am literally not able to find lxqt package to install. If LXQt is meant to be installed somehow differently than from this package, please point it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That repo is still there for compat reasons, but i'm glad that we made the transitions to Epel official repos now, the only thing not available is using groupinstall, so a safe easy way to do it is install the whole set in this way:

```
dnf install lxqt-about lxqt-common lxqt-config lxqt-globalkeys lxqt-notificationd lxqt-openssh-askpass lxqt-panel lxqt-policykit lxqt-powermanagement lxqt-qtplugin lxqt-runner lxqt-session network-manager-applet nm-connection-editor pcmanfm-qt qterminal-qt5
```

Comment: Thanks. I have minimal installation of centos. What other packages I need to be able boot to lxqt gui? I've tried to install group with `yum group install basic-desktop`, but it seems it does not want to install any new packages. Same with `desktop-platform` or `general-desktop`

Comment: Has there been any change in the past year, such that one can "groupinstall" these?  Also, can this be done with yum for CentOS 7, and then can select this desktop during graphical-login from the "cog/settings" icon?

Answer (score 0):

check fedora official lxqt wiki for details, also add this repo and check again, should work

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/heliocastro/lxqt/repo/epel-7/heliocastro-lxqt-epel-7.repo

at least try to compile it, regards.

Comment: After adding the repo yum will print this error message `https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/heliocastro/lxqt/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`

Comment: Also I did not find the informations regards Centos with LXQt  on Fedora wiki. And I would rather try to avoid compiling it myself if I can get version from official repo.